# Getting "undefined" with other data when getting data from JSON

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I am getting values from JSON using jQuery using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : 'outfitters.json',
                dataType : 'json',
                success : processTeam,
                error : function() {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        });

        function processTeam(data) {
            var company = data.company;
            $("h1").html(company);

            var locations;
            for ( i = 0; i < data.locations.length; i++) {

                locations += data.locations[i].name + "<br/>";

            }
            $("li").html(locations);

        }
```

Indeed I get expected output but with an extra "undefined" in the starting of the output like this:

```
undefinedKincardine
Killarney
Bon Echo
```

Moreover, I am using jQuery mobile list box, but its filling the values only in one listbox though it is supposed to show it in three separate ones.

```
<ul data-role="listview">
            <li>

            </li>

        </ul>
```

Any mistakes I am doing in my code?

Comment: What does `data.locations` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your variable `var locations = '';`

Comment: What about the error I am getting while appending them to li?

Comment: @user1890338 so you have multiple `li`s and only one is getting data appended to it?

Comment: @user1890338 could you edit the question to include the markup for the  other `li`s

Comment: I indeed have added the code for `li`s, you can see that in the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialize variable first.

```
var locations='';
```

because when you are trying to append un-initilized data.  so first it will be undefined + youvalue.  so you get `undefinedKincardine` for the first result

Answer (score 1):

Without initialize locations , you used it so ofcourse it's through undefined error message.

```
var locations = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your HTML is looks as below

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <h2 id="companyName">my list</h2>
        <div id="locationList"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then your `processTeam` should be as follow

```
var company = JSON.parse(data);

//setting company name
$('#companyName').text(company.company);

//setting the list view
//running a loop first
var locationsStr = "<ul data-role='listview'>";
$.each(company.locations, function(){
   locationsStr = locationsStr + "<li><a href='#'>"+this.name+"</a></li>";
});
locationsStr = locationsStr+ "</ul>";
$('#locationList').html(locationsStr);
$('#locationList ul').listview();
```

You can check out a working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/eTpSQ/1/